# Delaying View resolution until an Expander is Expanded

Tags: c#, xaml, caliburn.micro

We have a UI layout that creates a list of Expanders for an `ItemsControl`.
The `ItemsControl` is named Items and is by convention binding successfully to our view models internal list, where our viewmodel is of type `Conductor<SubViewModel>.Collection.OneActive`

my `SubViewModel` is a `Screen` and looks like this:

```
public class SubViewModel : Screen, ISubViewModel
{
    public bool IsVisible => true;
    public string GroupName => "MyGroupName";
    public bool HasValidationFailures => true;
    protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
    {
        //overridden to breakpoint on to see when the views get hooked up
    }
    //various properties and other viewModelly things which should be unimportant
}
```

The `ItemsControl` currently correctly creates an `Expander` for each child view model in the Items list, and the expanders content is also correctly finding the right view by the following Xaml:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Items">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:SubViewModel">
            <Expander Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                 cal:View.ApplyConventions="True"
                                 cal:View.Model="{Binding}">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" />
                        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ErrorIndicator}"
                                        Visibility="{Binding HasValidationFailures, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </Expander.Header>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This is to facilitate having different layouts as configured by the user. For example we currently bind the same Conductor to a different view which uses a `TabControl` instead, and allows the groups to be shown in separate tabs.
The tab control also correctly binds the view only when the tab is selected.

After a lot of research online I'm fairly certain I want an `ElementConvention` but I am having trouble working out what I need to do to get the convention to even get called for an `Expander`. I have followed a few examples I've found online and written this code to attempt a Convention:

```
ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<Expander>(Expander.IsExpandedProperty, "IsExpanded", "IsExpandedChanged")
            .ApplyBinding = (viewModelType, path, property, element, convention) =>
        {
            return true;
        };
```

However if I breakpoint on this Funcs body, it never gets hit, and the Views all get hooked up on `Expander` creation which is why I havn't put any logic in to check if the `Expander` is expanded...

I have also tried to force `ApplyConventions` by setting it on the expander... this was experimental but shows in my Xaml for completeness.

I'm happy to explore other routes that isn't a Custom Element Convention but I haven't really found much that would make me believe I should be doing it in a different way.